# How to convert c++ std::list element to multimap iterator

Tags: c++, list, stl, iterator, multimap

I have

```
std::list<multimap<std::string,std::string>::iterator> >
```

Now i have new element:

```
multimap<std::string,std::string>::value_type aNewMmapValue("foo1","test")
```

I want to avoid the need to set temp multimap and do insert to the new element just to get its iterator back 
so i could to push it back to the:

```
std::list<multimap<std::string,std::string>::iterator> >
```

can i somehow avoid this creation of the temp multimap.
Thanks

Comment: Please clear up list of what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to insert the key-value pair into a multimap before getting an iterator for it.

An iterator does not work by itself. If you are storing iterators from several different multimaps you probably need to store more than just an iterator in the list.

Perhaps:

1. a `pair<multimap<std::string,std::string>::iterator, multimap<std::string,std::string>::iterator>` where first is the iterator and second is the end-iterator.
2. a `pair<multimap<std::string,std::string>::iterator, multimap<std::string,std::string>*>` where first is the iterator, and second is a pointer to the multimap that the iterator belongs to.
3. some other kind of solution.

EDIT: I concur with Mykola Golubyev: It is often a bad idea to store iterators for a longer period of time, as the iterators may be invalidated.

Answer (score 2):

You have not specified the data type that you store in your `list`. Anyway, assuming that you want to add the value(s) pointed to by a particular key, you can call `list.insert(*mapIter)`.

```
multimap<std::string,std::string>::value_type aNewMmapValue("foo1","test")
```

You need to add this to your multimap via `map.insert`. This function returns an iterator. You can then safely add this iterator to your list.

```
std::list<multimap<std::string,std::string>::iterator> yourlist;
// ....
multimap<std::string,std::string>::iterator itr = 
                               yourmultimap.insert(aNewMmapValue);
yourlist.insert(itr);
```

Answer (score 1):

The type `std::multimap<std::string,std::string>::iterator` is an iterator to a `std::pair<const std::string, std::string>` **stored in a std::multimap**. If the element isn't stored in a multimap, it can't be referred to through a mulitmap iterator.

You may want to store use a `std::list<std::pair<std::string,std::string> >` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Don't store iterators. Use either const iterators or better way is store the pointers to the elements in the map.